# Python 2.7 accessibility for blind

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, accessibility

Hello I am planning on creating a program in Python 2.7 using a tkinter GUI. I am looking for some guidance on the best method to play text as audio in order to aid people with visual difficulties.

The text that will need to be played would be text on buttons and text within textboxes. are there any libraries I can import that can help me achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Many OSs have built in features that can do this on a user side... have you looked at, e.g. VoiceOver for OSX?

Comment: I want to implement it myself rather than rely on other softwaree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be 'no'. According to tcl/tk developer [Kevin Walzer](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-September/003480.html) "Tk doesn't support [screen readers]. I've looked into it a bit and it seems like a huge project to implement on a cross-platform basis."  See link for a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to develop an accessible GUI application in Python, you shouldn't use Tkinter since it is not accessible at all.
Consider using some framework that has bindings to native APIs/controls, for example, [WxPython](http://wxpython.org/) which is a Python port of [WxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org).